# Simple HTML DOM Parser - trigger click

Tags: javascript, php, html, simple-html-dom

Hi i'm having below scenario,

Fetching products from other 3rd party website,
Their product page having 3 different tabs and their default html structure is like this,

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">description</li>
  <li>Spec</li>
  <li>Gallery</li>
<ul>
<div>
  <div class="description">product descriptions goes here .... </div>
  <div class="spec"></div>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

Is i click on second tab (spec tab) then the html structure is (contents adding dynamically),

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">description</li>
  <li>Spec</li>
  <li>Gallery</li>
<ul>
<div>
  <div class="description">product descriptions goes here .... </div>
  <div class="spec"> Specs goes here </div>
  <div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

Because of the contents adding dynamically according to tab selection, i cant able to fetch complete contents. Is there any way to click other too and get all contents ?

Did anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: You will need to check the url that is being called when you click on the tab and get the contents (html/text) for that tab/page with a separate query (curl/file_get_contents) and then parse it with Simple HTML DOM..

Comment: Use the Network tab of your browser console to see the Ajax request that's made when you click the Spec tab. Then you can request that from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you asking here. but may be worth a try :

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0, x; x = tabs[i++];)
    x.click();
```